# Can't upgrade Pop version

Tags: pop-os, pipewire

I recently installed a software called, 'FaceSwap' and followed their steps.

At one point it asked me if I wanted to change Pipewire version which was a required step. I hit yes and everything was fine. Yesterday I tried to install a newer version of Pop, but got an error:

failed to update system: client error: calling FetchUpdates method failed: failed to exec 'apt-get full-upgrade --print-uris': status is unknown: exit status 100

I then tried updating packages with sudo apt upgrade, but got this error:

https://pastebin.com/7RhEvGP8

After doing sudo apt --fix-broken install I got this:

https://pastebin.com/jp8r7J9D

I then just entered pipewire into the terminal and got this:

https://pastebin.com/zsKN6NeT

This hasn't really bothered me until now, I've been trying to upgrade to Pop! version 22.10 and I keep getting this error while trying to.

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: It is better to [edit] and paste the errors into the question (and format them correctly) rather than requiring people click multiple links - it just makes it easier to read.